# set checkboxes checked after page refresh based on checkboxes values in the URL querystring

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, url, checkbox

I have a set of checkboxes:

```
    <input name="LocType" type="checkbox" value="Hospital"/>HOSPITALS&#160;&#160;
    <input name="LocType" type="checkbox"  value="Office"/>  PHYSICIAN OFFICES&#160;&#160;
    <input name="LocType" type="checkbox"  value="Emergency"/>EMERGENCY CENTERS&#160;&#160;
    <input name="LocType" type="checkbox"  value="Out-Patient"/>OUT-PATIENT CENTERS&#160;&#160;
    <input name="LocType" type="checkbox" value="Facility"/>FACILITIES
```

I have grabbed their values as follows and passed to the url, after page reloads with the passed querystring, i wanna check for whatever checkboxes values were passed and set those checkboxes to checked=true.

```
var url = "http://mysite.com/contact-us/Pages/LocationSearch.aspx?s=bcs_locations&k=";     
var checkboxValues = $("input[name=LocType]:checked").map(function() {
    return ' '+'bcslocationtype:'+"\"" + $(this).val() + "\"";}).get().join(" OR ");                 

         window.location= url +  checkboxValues;
```

When Hospitals and Emergency checkboxes are checked and hit search, URL looks like this:
http://mysite.com/contact-us/Pages/LocationSearch.aspx?s=bcs_locations&k= bcslocationtype:"Hospital" OR  bcslocationtype:"Emergency"

Now why is thing not working, I don't see anything wrong with this?its insde document.ready(){}

```
//Keep the selected chkboxes checked on page redirect
    var value = window.location.href.match(/[?&]k=([^&#]+)/) || [];
    if (value.length == 2) {
        $('input[name=LocType]').each(function (index) {
            if(value[1].indexOf($(this).val())>=0)
                this.prop("checked", true); 
            }); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the update to your code

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

   var value = window.location.href.match(/[?&]k=([^&#]+)/) || [];
   var actualValue = value[1].split(":")
    console.log(actualValue[1]);
    $('input[name=LocType]').each(function (index) {
            if(actualValue[1] === $(this).val()){
            //or use if(actualValue[1].indexOf($(this).val())>=0){
                $(this).prop("checked", true); 
            }

    }); 
});
```

Also note that, in order to access jquery related methods like 'prop', you need to wrap 'this' in '$'. So I updated your code from 'this' to '$(this)'. Also, what us the purpose of using 'bcslocationtype:"Hospital" ' as value. Why do you require 'bcslocationtype' as a value for variable k. Can't you just append k=hospital etc?

Also, you can do the same thing using aspx. I am not sure about the aspx code, but in Coldfusion I would do something like below: Assuming  'k' is the url variable name

```
 <input name="LocType" type="checkbox" value="Hospital" <cfif isDefined("URL.k") and URL.k eq "HOSPITAL">CHECKED</cfif> />HOSPITALS&#160;&#160;
```

The code within input tag to peruse is `<cfif isDefined("URL.k") and URL.k eq "HOSPITAL">CHECKED</cfif>`. It means, if I have a variable called 'k' defined and set in URL scope, and if the value is hospital, make it checked. Convert it into your asp code.